# Which preposition should I use: BY or WITH

Tags: prepositions

I'm writing a text and I'm not sure which preposition I should use in the following sentence:

> I should get married **by** 30

or

> I should get married **with** 30

Comment: I should get married by 30

Comment: 'I should get married with 30' sounds like more fun though!

Answer (score 2):

> I should get married by 30 -is correct.

You use 'by' when showing the limit of age there.

> I should get married with 30 - is incorrect.

Additionally, when you want to say someone whom are you married to...you use 'to'.

> I'm married to a doctor.

Comment: 'I should get married with 30' sounds like more fun though!

Comment: haha.. +1 that's right! The other may answer, "Ah, better marry with one only." ;)

Comment: In practice, you'd hear "I should get married by the time I'm 30" often as well.